# Apache Server shutting down even after changing the port 80 in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I am new user of XAMPP , I am facing a problem will opening Apache and MySQL servers. I have changed the ports from 80 to 8080 & 443 to 4433 in configuration files, stopped the port 80 service through control panel and even IIS services are also been blocked manually by me. But still I am facing the problem in launching Apache and MySQL sever. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

> [image: XAMPP]

Comment: Can you confirm/provide the xampp's server config file is the one you edited?

Comment: Yes @hjpotter92 m after reading your comment , I confirmed it again, the CONF file has been changed from port 80 to 8080, 443 to 4433 and I am 100 sure that my port 80 is not in use and even 8080 too (through task manager) :(

Comment: How can you verify port in use from task manager?? As per me not possible. Your logs suggest your port 80 is already in use. Please do following - (1.) Try this command and provide the log - `netstat -a -o -n | find ":80"`. If you are using Skype then kill that process, start Apache and then start Skype .. (2.) Comment out `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` in your `httpd.conf`

Comment: Thank u @hagrawal yes we can verify port using task manager , Taskmanager-->Details and yes hhtpd-ssl.conf is included and I have chenged it to 4433 but no positive result. After using the command netstat -a -o -n | find ":80" there is just a sudden pop-up console screen for a fraction of second no changes on the server.

Comment: From the task manager, you can know the process id but not port number .. You have execute that command in command prompt .. You to comment that line, which means for now you should not be including it your httpd.conf ..

Comment: the one you provided is not working @hagrawal but this one is working netstat -ao , port 80 is free now , even now the error remained same

Comment: Are typing or copy pasting my command ?? Please copy paste to avoid any error because it works for me .. Also please provide logs ..

Comment: [Sat Nov 14 21:07:46.483379 2015] [log_config:error] [pid 5076:tid 312] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : AH00649: could not open transfer log file G:/XAMPP/apache/logs/access.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Comment: yup your command line is not working for me @hagrawal and now port 80 is  free , but even then it's showing error